# Deleting data SQLServer using C# application

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, delete-row

I need to make a button that delete rows from my dataset in C#, but I want datagridview selected rows to be deleted, how do I do that?

This is what was in the professor instructions, but unfortunatelly this isn't working for me.

```
            int lineNum = int.Parse(lineDelete.Text.ToString());
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        sqlConn.Open();
        string deleteSqlQuery = "select * from Clientes order by ID";
        SqlDataAdapter deleteDA = new SqlDataAdapter(deleteSqlQuery, sqlConn);
        DataSet deleteDS = new DataSet();
        deleteDA.Fill(deleteDS, "Clientes");
        deleteDS.Tables["Clientes"].Rows[lineNum].Delete();
        SqlCommandBuilder deleteCB = new SqlCommandBuilder(deleteDA);
        deleteDA.Update(deleteDS, "Clientes");
        deleteDA.Dispose();
        deleteDS.Dispose();
        deleteCB.Dispose();
        sqlConn.Close();
        CliCadForm_Load(null, null);
        CustTBoxID.Text = "";
        CustTBoxNome.Text = "";
        CustTBoxDDD.Text = "";
        CustTBoxTel.Text = "";
        CustTBoxEnde.Text = "";
        CustTBoxENum.Text = "";
        CustTBoxEComp.Text = "";
        CustTBoxEBai.Text = "";
        CustTBoxEUF.Text = "";
        CustTBoxECid.Text = "";
        CustTBoxECEP.Text = "";
        lineDelete.Text = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, you can use something like this:

```
    private void DeleteSelectedRows()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();

            foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.SelectedRows)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Clientes WHERE ID="+row.Cells["ID"].Value, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            con.Close();
        }
    }
```